# Understanding the markings on a Fuse

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

Does anyone know what amp fuse is in a Heath/Zenith security motion sensor outdoor light has. The unit has a little fuse which is ceramic type fuse with markings on the silver ends, with ( F2H 250V ) on it. I have looked everywhere but no joy.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.swe-check.com.au/pages/learn_fuse_markings.php) i.e. top of the list when googling "fuse marking F2H".

It's a 2 amp fast acting fuse with high rupture current rated for 250 volt AC circuits. To find one you also need to measure it's length (often 20 mm). Common sizes: -

[image]